# Can't get lazyload-any to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading

I'm trying to get the whole div `.lazyload` to lazy load when you scroll down but I can't seem to get it correct. Plugin (https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any)

`$('.lazyload').lazyload();`

```
<div class="lazyload">
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="lazyload">
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8y4fdmL0/146/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't commented your `.projectWrap` div. So in your html you need to replace each occurence of `div.projectWrap` from:

```
<div class="projectWrap">
</div>
```

To

```
<!--
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
-->
```

```js
$('.lazyload').lazyload();
```

```css
.projectWrap { background-color:#000; margin-bottom:300px; height:450px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://emn178.github.io/jquery-lazyload-any/src/jquery.lazyload-any.js"></script>

<div class="lazyload">
  <!--
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
  -->
</div>

<div class="lazyload">
  <!--
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
  -->
</div>

<div class="lazyload">
  <!--
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
  -->
</div>

<div class="lazyload">
  <!--
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
  -->
</div>

<div class="lazyload">
  <!--
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
  -->
</div>

<div class="lazyload">
  <!--
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
  -->
</div>

<div class="lazyload">
  <!--
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
  -->
</div>

<div class="lazyload">
  <!--
  <div class="projectWrap">
  </div>
  -->
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's happening to fast but it doesn't seem to be lazy loading, it just looks like to loaded everything at once. http://jsfiddle.net/8y4fdmL0/147/

Comment: Are you sure that you use lazyload correctly ? See [this tutorial](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) of how and when  to use `lazyload`

Comment: @user2252219 Answer completely updated, the reason of problem was completely other, than described before, also take a look on working code snippet)

Comment: Ivaeyko This is probably a dumb question but doesn't commenting make that html markup not show on the website? How can I still be seeing projectWrap if I commented it out?

Comment: Ah I see. Last question. Is it possible to add a fade in effect to the loading? `    function load(.lazyload)
    {
      .lazyload.fadeOut(0, function() {
        .lazyload.fadeIn(1000);
      });
    }
    $('.lazyload').lazyload({load: load});`

Comment: Sure that's possible, see lazyload-any example section as sample: https://github.com/emn178/jquery-lazyload-any/blob/master/README.md#example